# Is it possible to make GCR Artifact registry immutable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

Is there a way to disable the possibility to update an image?

[image]

Comment: I think the only solution is to specify images by digest as in `LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY/IMAGE-DIGEST` Images by digest are immutable.

Comment: Agree with @JohnHanley. You can store the image with their digest to not override them, but nothing prevent you to update an image. There is no deletion/update protection.

Answer (score 0):

now they do (still in preview): [edit repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yCLZ.png)